# Retrofit 2.1.0 onFailure() called while respose 200 OK

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm new to use Retrofit and start with Retrofit 2.1.0.
I get respose 200 OK but in my `call.enqueue` always run `onFailure()`, logically it has to run `onResponse()`. I really dont know why and search the same problem but their explanation not fix my problem. Can someone save my day...?

I have a POST to my DB with API

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/v1/meetups/")
Call<Result<Meeting>> createMeeting(@Field("name") String name,
                                    @Field("date_start") String date_start,
                                    @Field("date_ended") String date_ended,
                                    @Field("location") String location,
                                    @Field("latitude") Double latitude,
                                    @Field("longitude") Double longitude,
                                    @Field("points") Integer points,
                                    @Field("member_ids") String member_ids);
```

This is how i run in my activity

```
Call<Result<Meeting>> call = mClient.createMeeting(meeting.getName(), meeting.getDate_start(), meeting.getDate_ended(),
            meeting.getLocation(), meeting.getLatitude(), meeting.getLongitude(), meeting.getPoints(), meeting.getMember_ids());
    Log.e("URL",String.valueOf(call.request().hashCode()));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Result<Meeting>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result<Meeting>> call, Response<Result<Meeting>> response) {
            Log.e("Response Code", String.valueOf(response.code()));
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.e("Meeting ", "Dibuat");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Meeting Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(i);
                ((Activity) mContext).finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Create Meeting Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response Error: HTTP Code " + String.valueOf(response.code()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG + "onResponse", String.valueOf(response.raw().toString()));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result<Meeting>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("On Failure", "Working");

        }
    });
```

here is my Meeting Model

```
public class Meeting {
private String _id;
private String name;
private String date_start;
private String date_ended;
private String status;
private String location;
private String member_ids;
private Double latitude;
private Double longitude;
private Integer points;
private Group group;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public String get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(String _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
...
...
}
```

The problem is when I intentionally input wrong attribute in my Meeting, it return error code 500 and `onResponse()` is working, give `response.isSuccessful() == false` and `Log.e()` output is "Create Meeting Failed". But when I input right attribute, it give 200 OK, POST in my DB, but `onFailure()` is working and run `Log.e()` "On Failure : Working".

Comment: first, `isSuccessful()` returns `true` if the status code is `2xx..3xx`. In your case this evaluates to false, so I am curious what the status code might be.
Additional, what does a subsequent `response.message()` reveal?

Comment: @sschrass I edit my code to get the message at `onFailure()` with `Log.e("On Failure", t.getMessage());` and i get message `On Failure: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 3 column 12 path $.data`

Comment: You are using JsonArray while parsing or binding data use JsonObject

Comment: @ysl Yes I get it know, i have to change parsing data use JsonArray like the Answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These steps may help you:

- Figure out the response JSON structure from the server. You can try this by using postman or curl.
- Adjust the Call parameters into the response, for example, if your response like this:

  ```
  {
      "success": true,
      "data": [
          {
              "_id": "59cb12c0abb4713d6632c6ef",
              "name": "Meeting 1",
              "date_start": "2609-03-10T13:02:40.000Z",
              "date_ended": "2609-03-10T13:03:00.000Z",
              ...
          }
      ]
  }
  ```

and with custom model for result, your call will be like this:

```
Call<Result<List<Meeting>>> call
```

---

For your problem with `IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY`, you can change your API code like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/v1/meetups/")
Call<Result<List<Meeting>>> createMeeting(@Field("name") String name, @Field("date_start") String date_start, @Field("date_ended") String date_ended, @Field("location") String location, @Field("latitude") Double latitude, @Field("longitude") Double longitude, @Field("points") Integer points, @Field("member_ids") String member_ids);
```

You can use your call like this:

```
    Call<Result<List<Meeting>>> call = mClient.createMeeting(meeting.getName(), meeting.getDate_start(), meeting.getDate_ended(), meeting.getLocation(), meeting.getLatitude(), meeting.getLongitude(), meeting.getPoints(), meeting.getMember_ids());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Result<List<Meeting>>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Result<List<Meeting>>> call, Response<Result<List<Meeting>>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Meeting Dibuat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(i);
                ((Activity) mContext).finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Membuat Meeting Gagal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response Error: HTTP Code " + String.valueOf(response.code()),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG + "onResponse", String.valueOf(response.raw().toString()));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Result<List<Meeting>>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("On Failure", t.getMessage());

        }
    });
```

Note that you have to change `Result<Meeting>` into `Result<List<Meeting>>`